# Resolving a model using multiple columns in a Laravel route

Tags: laravel, eloquent, url-routing

I'm trying to register a route to fetch a single model automatically based on multiple columns. For example:

```
Route:get( 'sample/{myModel:status}/{myModel:slug}', [ SomeController:class, 'show' );
```

Let's access this URI:

```
www.example.com/sample/publish/this-is-a-slug
```

Now what I expect to get in my controller is a single `myModel` instance, which has a `status` column equal to `publish` and a `slug` column equal to `this-is-a-slug`. Is this possible?

Trying to register the above route will result in a reference error:

```
Route pattern "/sample/{myModel}/{myModel}" cannot reference variable name "myModel" more than once.
```

Now I can just drop the model name and do the query in my controller, but I wonder if it's possible to inject a model into a controller using more than 1 column. The `slug` column is not unique, but the combination of `slug` and `status` is.

Answer (score 0):

You may define the route like this,

```
Route::get('sample/{model_by_status}/{slug}', [ SomeController:class, 'show'] );
```

Then you can add route binding in the boot() method of RouteServiceProvider.php like this,

```
Route::bind('model_by_status', function($value){
  $slug = request()->route('slug');
  return myModel::where([
    'status' => $value,
    'slug' => $slug,
  ])->firstOrFail();
});
```

And in your controller method you need to declare the show method like this

```
public function show(myModel $model_by_status){
 
}
```

**Note that the naming is important here. model_by_status (whatever in your case) must be same in all those three places**